# What causes localized_options on a menu link to be set to (boolean) FALSE?

Tags: 6, routes

I'm having a problem with one of our existing Drupal 6 websites where if you go to Build > Menu > Primary Links it causes 500 error.

The error message is: `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /var/www/sitename/htdocs/includes/common.inc on line 1632` which is corresponding to the function L which creates links, and particularly the part that says:

```
// Merge in defaults.
$options += array(
  'attributes' => array(),
  'html' => FALSE,
);
```

Which basically means, as I understand, `$options` is set but it's not an array.

So I've further investigated the problem, and `dpm`'d the menu tree to investigate, and found one link in the tree array to have `localized_options` set to `(boolean) FALSE` where all other links had an array as `localized_options`.

Now I'm wondering where this FALSE could come from, and how to correct it? Obviously I don't want to hack the default `menu.module` and set a check for boolean, so I'm looking for the proper solution and the origin of the issue.

The link was probably (- because I don't enter the site's content) put in manually through the admin interface, so it's not a custom module `hook_menu` link or anything. I've tried looking in `{menu_links}` and `{menu_router}` tables in MySQL Workbench but I have no idea where the localized_options comes from. It could be on of the serialized data in the table.

Comment: So I've managed to find a temporary workaround by editing the menu item by directly typing in the path `admin/build/menu/item/6813/edit` and setting a "Title" attribute so that the `localized_options` array won't be empty. This works for now, but in the future I'd like to avoid a similar situation so I'm still looking for an answer.

Comment: The instructions from http://drupal.org/node/362799#comment-1542118 (as linked in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24086/l-is-not-being-called-correctly-in-menu-inc?rq=1 ) might be of use. The whole discussion is a fruitful read as well.